# Rails 4 - On click render ruby partial in js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm trying to render a partial on click through a JavaScript function. The partial is a checkbox form but when I click the element that has an event listener attached to it nothing happens but I also get no errors.

```
$("#organization_profile_lock").addEventListener("onclick", profileLockConfig);

function profileLockConfig() {
  $("#organization_profile_lock").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "setup_organizations/_profile_lock_settings") %>");
}
```

This is the controller which handles the change

```
def edit_configuration
  @form = SuperAdmins::EditConfigurationForm.new(@organization)
end
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this functionality, thanks in advance:)!

Comment: I'm using jquery $() is short hand for $(document).ready

Comment: I'm not using turbolinks

Comment: I tried `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#organization_profile_lock").click(function profileLockConfig() {
        $("#organization_profile_lock").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "setup_organizations/_profile_lock_settings") %>");
    })
})` but still nothing happens, do you have any suggestions on how I could get this to work?

Comment: I'm sure, I just got rid of the partial and did it in the view instead which worked.